# Removing UIView in one size class, causes missing constraint in other size classes

Tags: ios, orientation, size-classes

Let's say we have UILabel A. It will be installed by default. Tie it to let's say trailing and top margins to have a real position for it.

[image: label with trailing/top constraints]

Let's say we want to hide this label in landscape.

In Interface Builder, on the right hand side below View, we click the + next to Installed, and make a *hC* size class, and uncheck Installed for that size class.

[image]

Now auto layout errors occurs:

- Need constraints for: Y position
- Need constraints for: X position

[image]

What is the problem here? What did I do wrong?

Xcode 9.2

**Update 1** I noticed something strange. After the errors were reported, I selected one of the "missing" (but existing) constraints, and uninstalled it, then installed it again (= just two taps on Installed button), and the errors disappeared.

Comment: Can you show some screen shots

Comment: is any other things are dependent on that UILabel  ?

Comment: is any other things are dependent on that UILabel  ?

Comment: Yes I can, give me a second. Btw in the meantime I noticed that, after the steps above, I added the exact same constraints again (ie ending up with exact two copies of X and Y position constraints), things work. I even disabled the first constraints; they seem to be not needed/used anymore.

Comment: Then there might be xcode issue . But for iphone it is not true `wR hC ` for iphone landscape it should be   `CR hC ` while for plus devices   `wR hC ` is true so check that accordingly :)

Comment: ok my bad, I meant `hC` which should cover plus and other iphones.

Comment: Then there might be xcode issue . But for iphone it is not true `wR hC ` for iphone landscape it should be   `CR hC ` while for plus devices   `wR hC ` is true so check that accordingly :)

Comment: Added screenshots... btw I added the landscape size class constraint by opening landscape orientation and then clicking + on the button, adding hC, unchecking Installed, then switch back to portrait - the errors display there.

Comment: Updated my question with some more info - somehow xcode could find the constraints if I clicked Installed twice on one of them.